# Why scala Future.never uses CountDownLatch?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

Here is the implementation of scala.concurrent.Future.never from Scala 2.12.x:

```
final object never extends Future[Nothing] {

@throws(classOf[TimeoutException])
@throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
override def ready(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): this.type = {
  atMost match {
    case e if e eq Duration.Undefined => throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot wait for Undefined period")
    case Duration.Inf        => new CountDownLatch(1).await()
    case Duration.MinusInf   => // Drop out
    case f: FiniteDuration   =>
      if (f > Duration.Zero) new CountDownLatch(1).await(f.toNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
  }
  throw new TimeoutException(s"Future timed out after [$atMost]")
}
...
```

As you can see it uses `new CountDownLatch(1).await()` to block current thread. Why is it better than `Thread.sleep()`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, how do you `Thread.sleep` forever? A loop? `MAX_LONG`? Looks sorta clumsy. `await()` just seems cleaner. Besides, it supports durations with nanosecond granularity.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like thats implementing from `Awaitable.scala`. Your right blocking isnt good, but it is documented.

```
/**
 * An object that may eventually be completed with a result value of type `T` which may be
 * awaited using blocking methods.
 *
 * The [[Await]] object provides methods that allow accessing the result of an `Awaitable`
 * by blocking the current thread until the `Awaitable` has been completed or a timeout has
 * occurred.
 */
trait Awaitable[+T] {

  /**
   * Await the "completed" state of this `Awaitable`.
   *
   * '''''This method should not be called directly; use [[Await.ready]] instead.'''''
   *
   * @param  atMost
   *         maximum wait time, which may be negative (no waiting is done),
   *         [[scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf Duration.Inf]] for unbounded waiting, or a finite positive
   *         duration
   * @return this `Awaitable`
   * @throws InterruptedException     if the current thread is interrupted while waiting
   * @throws TimeoutException         if after waiting for the specified time this `Awaitable` is still not ready
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if `atMost` is [[scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Undefined Duration.Undefined]]
   */
  @throws(classOf[TimeoutException])
  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  def ready(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): this.type

  ...
}
```